# Importing a partially trained decision tree with River Library

Tags: python, decision-tree

I'm using the River Library to build incremental decision trees in Python. Once the tree is partially trained, I can save its strucuture in a dataframe using the 'to_dataframe' method. I would like to know if it is possible to import this kind of structure to continue the incremental training with the rest of the dataset, with no loss of information from the previous training. I could not find an 'import tree' like method in the documentation. Thank you.

A simple example:

```
from river.tree import HoeffdingTreeClassifier

model = tree.HoeffdingTreeClassifier(grace_period=50)

for x, y in dataset1:
    model.learn_one(x, y)

df_tree = model.to_dataframe()
```

**now I need to import the partially trained tree to continue the incremental training in another run, using dataset2, for instance

Comment: You probably want to be pickling and unpickling to save and load your models! Ref: [save and load models](https://riverml.xyz/0.15.0/faq/#how-do-i-save-and-load-models)

Comment: question answered, thank you very much Priyank! Actually it is in the documentation, missed that.